# iPhone 4 camera roll "time created" information

Tags: ios, photos

I recently took a photo with my iPhone 4 and soon after e-mailed it to someone. When I downloaded my photos to my computer I noticed that the "time created" information showed a time that was after I had e-mailed the photo. How is that possible?

Comment: What OS downloaded the photos? What software catalogs / shows the time? Can you log in to iCloud.com and verify the info separately?

Answer (score 1):

Time created means **time transferred to your computer**. It is the time when the photo landed to whichever folder you downloaded it to, on your computer.

So if you transferred the photo on *Monday 1st August 2015*, then that is the Date Created shown.

Try downloading an mp3 file from the internet to your computer. You will see that the Date Created is the **date that the file enters your computer**. While the date of its creation was (obviously) earlier.